# One word to refer to this list

Tags: single-word-requests

We are attending a developer conference.

The host has arranged various talks. They are scheduled in specific time slots.

We are attending that event as a team. One of us has assigned who should attend which talk and prepared a list...

What to call "that" list? Sessions manifest? Attendance manifest?

PS: not sure why I like the word manifest...

Answer (score 1):

"manifest" is a very cool word, I don't blame you a bit. But technically, it probably doesn't apply here in any of the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manifest) noun senses:

> A document listing a ship’s contents, cargo, passengers, and crew, for
>   the use of customs officers.
>
> 1.1A list of passengers or cargo in an aircraft.
>
> 1.2A list of the wagons forming a freight train.

(I doubt that western civilisation will fall if you succumb to temptation and extend definition 1.1 to cover this, though.)

[Register](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/register) is perhaps closer to the mark:

> 1An official list or record of names or items:

"Sessions manifest / register" probably isn't that appropriate, because the sessions will occur regardless of whether any member of your team attends or not.

Attendance register might be an option; though you could argue that it's not really registering all of the people who attend.

Session assignments register (abbreviated to "the sessions register", abbreviated further to "the register", which is as close to one word as you're likely to get) could do it.

But on the other hand a word that you already used (list) would be just as effective and shorter as well.

Answer (score 1):

"Session assignments list" is simple, direct, and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

**schedule** (*noun*):

a plan for carrying out a process or procedure, giving lists of intended events and times

> '*we have drawn up an engineering schedule*'
>
> '*The Supporters' Trust has drawn up a fund-raising schedule with several events planned for the close season.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: The problem with this is people quickly take to understand it as the agenda for the day as opposed to what I am trying to refer to...

Comment: Hi @deostroll, I think you may incur the same problem, whichever word you use. A schedule is not an agenda. If you specify as 'Staff Attendance Schedule', that should probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call the list, in keeping to your one-word request, simply either *Assignments* or *Appointments*.

Both words imply that another person has, with forethought, given you the duty to attend specific sessions. And the context negates the need for other words (like *Sessions*). You all know you're going to the conference.

> [*Assignment*:](https://www.wordnik.com/words/assignment) That which has been assigned, as a particular task or duty.
>
> [*Appointment*:](https://www.wordnik.com/words/appointment) An arrangement to do something ... at a particular time and place